# How to set the origin while drag in d3.js in v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am facing a jump issue when I drag a `<rect>`.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966256/how-to-set-the-origin-drag-origin-for-drag-behavior-in-d3-javascript-library) they suggest to use [`drag.origin()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Drag-Behavior#origin) but D3 v4 version doesn't have this method anymore.

Can some body suggest how to solve the jump issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of `origin` use `subject`.

So this

```
 .origin(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
    })
```

will become

```
 .subject(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
    })
```

Working fiddle using d3 v4 is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/2s0yobhm/1/)

API reference [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag_subject)